# How can I make a like button using a checkbox to store randomly generated quotes into an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, object

I have done a randomly generated quote generator using math.random shown and I want to be able to have a like button that is able to collect all of the liked quotes into another array so it can be able to be displayed inside of another popup box.  So this is what I have so far with a checkbox button inside of my array an object named like

```
var quotes = [
{verses: "This is my first quote", chapter: "Psalm 139:7-10", data: "Never be Lost", id: "like1", like: '<input type="checkbox" name="like" id="like1"><label for="like1"><img src="not_liked.svg" alt="Wanna Like It? " width="16"></label>'},
{verses: "This is my second quote", chapter: "Matthew 27:32-44", data: "The Crucifixion of Jesus", id: "like2", like: '<input type="checkbox" name="like" id="like2"><label for="like1"><img src="not_liked.svg" alt="Wanna Like It? " width="16"></label>'},]$(document).ready(function () {
console.log(likedVerses);
function showQuote () {
    var init = Object.keys(quotes);
    var rng = init[Math.floor(Math.random()*init.length)];
    $('.quote').html(quotes[rng].verses);
    $('.name').html(quotes[rng].chapter);
    $('.meaning').html(quotes[rng].data);
    $('.like').html(quotes[rng].like);
}});
```

Then I added a for loop looping through the array inside of my document.ready function

```
    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < quotes.length; i++){
        if(quotes[i].id === this.id){
            if ($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
                
            }
            else {
                likedVerses.push(quotes[i])
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Basically I would like to have a checkbox that is assigned to each randomly generated quote and when it's checked, it'll store the objects into an array.  I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: When asking a language-specific question, the first tag you add should be for the language in which you're coding. Please [edit] your post and replace one of the tags with the tag for that language.

Comment: Get rid of `var init = Object.keys(quotes);` and change `var rng = init[Math.floor(Math.random()*init.length)];` to `var rng = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random()*quotes.length)];`.

Comment: Note that you don't need to use a for loop these days, just use `find`; see answers to [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7364150/215552).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Would you know on how I can get a function working for a checkbox with having a checkbox being inside of the array/object

Answer (score 0):

I have done a .find method and was able to loop through the array so I can be able to display it in my HTML

```
    $('#like1').on('click', function () {
    var versesFind = $(".quote");
    var nameFind = $(".name");
    var meaningFind = $(".meaning")
    $("div").find(versesFind, nameFind, meaningFind).each(function () {
        likedVerses[likedVerses.length]={'verses':$(versesFind).html(), 'name':$(nameFind).html(), 'meaning':$(meaningFind).html()}
    });
    $('.likedVersesHtml').html("");
    for (var j = 0; j < likedVerses.length; j++){
        $('.likedVersesHtml').append('<div>' + likedVerses[j].verses + '</div>' + '<div>' + likedVerses[j].name + '</div>' + '<div>' + likedVerses[j].meaning + '</div>');
    }
});
```